# can CAAnimationGroup automatically determine the duration based on animations in it?

Tags: ios, core-animation

If there's **5 animations** in a `CAAnimationGroup`,`g1`, I have to calculate the duration of `g1`, I'm wondering whether there's a way the `g1` can automatically calculate the duration to run all animations of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can quite easily get the longest duration of all the animations in the group with a little  "`valueForKeyPath`-magic".

```
// The longest of all the durations in the group.
NSNumber *groupDuration = [group.animations valueForKeyPath:@"@max.duration"];
```

Then you could do whatever you want with that value. It is a `NSSNumber` so you need to get the float or double value if you want to set it as the duration of the group.

```
group.duration = [groupDuration doubleValue];
```

### Edit

As [Duncan C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205185/duncan-c) pointed out: the above code to calculate the total duration will only work if all animations start immediately. One way around that could be to add a category on `CAAnimation` that adds a method for the `endTime`. Like this:

```
//  CAAnimation+EndTime.h
@interface CAAnimation (EndTime)
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) CGFloat endTime;
@end


//  CAAnimation+EndTime.m
@implementation CAAnimation (EndTime)

- (CGFloat)endTime {
    CGFloat endTime = self.duration;
    if (self.beginTime > 0.0) {
        endTime+= self.beginTime - CACurrentMediaTime();
    }
    return endTime;
}

@end
```

With that category in place you could use the above valueForKeyPath: approach like this

```
// The latest end time of all the animations in the group.
NSNumber *groupDuration = [group.animations valueForKeyPath:@"@max.endTime"];
```

#### Note

My implementation of `endTime` above would not cover *all* cases to calculate the actual end time of the animation. For example it doesn't take timeOffset into account or animations that have a begin time relative to something other than the current time. It does however take the two most common cases into consideration: start immediately and start some tome from "now".

Comment: You would need to write code that walks all the animations in the group, checking the beginTime + the duration and looking for the latest END time, not just the longest duration. The main reason I use animation groups is to chain a sequence of animations. And if there are groups within groups, you'd have to handle that as well. You'd also have to decide what duration meant. If the whole group is set to start at some point in the future (using a begin time offset from CACurrentMediaTime) then should that count as part of the duration?

Comment: How about a category on `CAAnimation` to calculate the `endTime` from its `beginTime` and `duration`?